# Numbers without arithmetic progressions on the board

Tags: number-theory

Girl wrote on the board the numbers $0$ and $1$. Every minute, she wrote on the board the smallest positive integer that does not form an arithmetic progression with any two numbers recorded earlier. It will writen on a dlackboard number $2015$?

*Will not be. $2015 = 2202122_3$ Numbers with deuces in binary notation on board will not appear. But how to prove it ...*

Comment: It is highly recommended to show some effort. What have you tried? Also, to me the question is not very coherent... Is it to find whether the girl will write $2015$?

Comment: I think these are the same as the numbers which, in base $3$, are written without the digit $2$.   https://oeis.org/A005836  (in which case, the answer is No by a straightforward computation).

Comment: I think you mean "ternary notation" where it says "binary notation"?